# virt manager "The emulator may not have search permissions for the path"

Tags: linux, fedora, virtual-machine, virt-manager

I am trying to set up a VM on Fedora 27 but when I go to create one and pick an ISO I get the message

```
The emulator may not have search permissions for the path '/path/to/fedora.iso'
```

If I click yes to fix it I get the error

```
Errors were encountered changing permissions for the following directories: 
/run/media/user : [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/run/media/user'
It is very likely the VM will fail to start up.
```

Like the message says. The VM does fail to start up. When I searched the problem I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722034/permission-error-in-virtual-machine-manager) suggesting running virt-manager with sudo but that gives the output.

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(virt-manager:14616): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

What should I do to get virt manager working?

Comment: Are the .iso files stored in virt-manager's own pool, with the correct permissions?

Comment: @Mioriin I set all the isos to 777 but still no luck. Anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: Copy/move the files to libvirt's storage pool. `virt-manager` doesn't have permission to access other users' directories and devices. Even when run as root. (you can change this is SElinux, but it's less hassle to just copy the .iso over)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to run nautilus as admin and change group permissions for the user you choose. Make sure that user is in the libvirt group.

1. #sudo -i
2. #nautilus

If you need a graphical tool for users and group permittions administration, LXQT-admin-tool is the easiest way I found. https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-admin